# SSRS Duplicating Date Values Within Rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS package, and within it, the dates are being duplicated across the columns. For example,

```
select [demographic columns], hireDate, transferDate, promotionDate
from userTable
where [conditions are met]
```

In my SSMS query window, sample results would be something like:

```
 12345 | John | Doe | 01-15-2013 |    null    |    null
 23456 | Jane | Doe | 12-12-2012 | 03-15-2014 |    null
 74883 | Test | Doe | 02-05-2014 | 06-06-2016 | 05-22-2015
```

However, when I run the exact same query in SSRS, or call the same query via stored proc to my SSRS package, I get duplicated date values in any date fields like below (SSRS converts the nulls to whitespace*); also it seems to take the first date (in my queries my first row's first date is 4-14-2017, and that date is everywhere, almost as though the date is cached for the entire report:

```
 12345 | John | Doe | 01-15-2013 |            |  
 23456 | Jane | Doe | 12-12-2012 | 12-12-2012 |      
 74883 | Test | Doe | 02-05-2014 | 02-05-2014 | 02-05-2014
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Are you sure your report has the right fields in the right places? e.g. Your column header could be "transfer date" or whatever, but maybe it's incorrectly putting the hiredate data in it?

Comment: Yup; opened the dataset and fields section and verified field source and field names are correct. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, the only thing I would have maybe thought could be the case is if you have some weird expression on the column like `=IIF(isNothing(Fields!transferDate.Value), Fields!transferDate.Value, Fields!hireDate.Value)` but if you're saying that's not the case then I can't really think of why you'd see something like that in SSRS.

Comment: In looking into this issue, I noticed an error in my initial post; edited for accuracy*

Comment: if you post that as answer I'll mark. That queued me to it. I was messing with special formatting on the column. The dataset doesn't show that on the special properties of the column. /faceplm; thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the only reason I could think for behaviour like that in SSRS is if there's some expression modifying the column, so looking through anything of the expressions that might modify the column should give you your answer.